# AFNetworking + JSONKit not working together

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, afnetworking, jsonkit

AFNetworking + JSONKit + iOS 5.0+ = JSON parsing does not work (returns nil objects when trying to parse).

AFNetworking + iOS 5.0+ = JSON parsing works fine.

AFNetworking + JSONKit + iOS 4.X = JSON Parsing works

AFNetworking + iOS 4.X = JSON Parsing doesn't work (because NSJSONSerializer is only available for iOS5.0+).

How do I solve this problem? Snippet of code:

```
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    if([sender respondsToSelector:finish])
    {
        NSArray *responseArray = JSON;
        [sender performSelector:finish withObject:JSON];
    }
} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"Error retrieving: %@\n%@", error, response);
    if([sender respondsToSelector:fail])
    {
        [sender performSelector:fail];
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange that JSONKit isn't working with iOS 5... Nonetheless, there is a simple way to override JSONKit for JSON encode / decode, and first try NSJSONSerialization, if that's available. Simply add `#define _AFNETWORKING_PREFER_NSJSONSERIALIZATION_` to a header file in the project (`Prefix.pch`, perhaps), and you should be all set.

Comment: Thanks. I just switched over to SBJSON however and it worked fine.